# Ratyrate stars displayed vertically when using bootstrap

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get `ratyrate` working with `Bootstrap`.

This gem works fine if I disable all styling in my application layout but when I enable bootstrap it displays each star on a different line / paragraph, like this:

- ( *)
- ( *)
- ( *)

instead of: ( *) ... ( *) ... ( *)

(see comments for a link to a screen shot).

I've tried wrapping the `rating_for` call in the bootstrap "form-inline" class, but it didn't work, see `show.html.erb` code:

```
...
<p><strong>User:</strong>
  <%= @user_activity.user_id %>
  <strong>Activity:</strong>
  <%= @user_activity.activity_id %>
</p>

Rating  : 
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-control" >
    <div class="control-group inline">
      <%= rating_for @user_activity, "rating", disable_after_rate: false %>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_activity_path(@user_activity) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', user_activities_path %>
...
```

'application.css.scss' is:

```
// import the CSS framework
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap-slider";

.inline {
    display:inline-block !important;
}
```

'application.js' is:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery.raty
//= require ratyrate
//= require bootstrap-slider
```

How do I override the CSS to get the stars on a single horizontal alignment?

Comment: Here is a link to image: https://github.com/wazery/ratyrate/issues/90

Answer (score 1):

Resolution: < img > tag was inheriting .img-responsive from bootstrap!

So, I spoke to a friend who suggested the following:

> Well, I don’t know how to fix, but I’ll tell you what I do to fix these issues.
>
> 1) Check I’ve loaded the stylesheet for the particular library I’m using (you are sure you have the ratyrate.css on the page are you?)
>
> 2) Try it without bootstrap loaded - does it work then?
>
> 3) Assume there is a style conflict and try to find it:
>
> - Load the page in Google Chrome
> - Right click the thing that is broken (stars in your case) and click “Inspect Element”
> - On the right hand tab you’ll see a list of styles
> - Start ticking and unpicking various ones until you find the one that is causing everything to be broken.
>
> Once you know which style is causing problems, you can write a new style to override it. Simples :) (he says!)
>
> Hope that helps!

I did as he said, and found the offending CSS item. Disabling the 'display: block;' made the stars align horizontally. Hooray!! I could also see in Chrome's inspect element tool that the style of the < img > tag said that .img-responsive was being used.

A search for "img_responsive" found this entry in the 'framework_and_overrides.css.scss' file

```
// make all images responsive by default
img {
  @extend .img-responsive;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

Comment the "@extend..." line and it works just great :-)

```
// make all images responsive by default
img {
  // @extend .img-responsive;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

Guess I will need to make each image individually responsive now, but at least my stars are aligned!!!

p.s. I deleted all the < form > and < div > tags around the '<%= ratings_for ... %> call in original question as they were not needed.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I had the same problem and your solution fixed it for me too - however the file the css was in for me was 1st_load_framework.css.scss